# Recover unknown vectors with dot-product queries

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, vector-spaces

Suppose there are $n$ unknown unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$, 
$V=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, no two identical.
Your task is to determine the vectors in $V$.
The only tool at your disposal is to query a particular vector $v_i$ and
learn what is its dot product with your query vector $v$, which $v$
is your choice. So your query will return $v \cdot v_i$.

My question is:

> ***Q***. What is the best strategy to uniquely determine $V$, where "best" is
>   the fewest number of queries, almost surely, as a function of $n$ and $d$?

"Almost surely" is to avoid choosing a query vector identical to one of the 
unknown vectors.

---

*Example*. $n=3$, $d=2$. Let the unknown vector be $V=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ with
\begin{eqnarray}
v_1 & = & (1,0) \\
v_2 & = & (0,1) \\
v_3 & = & \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)
\end{eqnarray}
$v_3$ is $(1,1)$ normalized to unit length.
Let's say we choose just one $v=(-1/2,1)$ normalized as our query vector:
$$
v=\left( -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \right)
$$

---

[image: Arrows]

---

Then we could query with $v \cdot v_i$:
\begin{eqnarray}
v \cdot v_1 & = & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \\
v \cdot v_2 & = &  \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\\
v \cdot v_3 & = & \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}
\end{eqnarray}
Knowing these dot products, and that $|v_1|=|v_2|=|v_3|=1$,
we have $6$ unknowns and $6$ equations, and indeed the original
$\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ constitute a solution.
But only one of eight solutions, e.g.:
\begin{eqnarray}
v_1 & = & \left( -\frac{3}{5}, -\frac{4}{5} \right) \\
v_2 & = & \left( -\frac{4}{5}, \frac{3}{5} \right) \\
v_3 & = & \left( -\frac{7}{5 \sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{5 \sqrt{2}} \right)
\end{eqnarray}

So which and how many additional queries are needed to pin down uniquely the unknown $V$?
One may use many different query vectors,
if that's advantageous; above I just used one, $v$.

Comment: There is the obvious strategy involving nd queries with a known orthonormal frame. Indeed, one needs nd queries in this case unless one finds some components of the mystery vectors are zero: any nonzero unknown could appear with positive or negative sign.  Gerhard "Almost Surely ND Are Best" Paseman, 2019.05.31.

Comment: Why is this presented as one problem, as opposed to $n$ completely separate problems?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg: Feel free to concentrate on specific $n$ & $d$. I am hoping that considering all as variants of the same general question will clarify. And I wouldn't want to proliferate questions unnecessarily.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant.  Let s(d,n) be the solution to your problem.  It appears that s(d,n)=ns(d,1).  So why not just ask for the value of s(d,1)?

Comment: (I interpret a single query to be a choice of an i and a query vector v.  If you really meant that a single query is a query vector v, applied to all n unknown vectors, that would answer my question.)

Comment: @StevenLandsburg: I see... Have to think about this. I meant a single query to be $v \cdot v_i$. Because there is freedom to choose different query vectors $v$, it seems conceivable that intelligent choice of query vectors reduces the total number of queries. But perhaps I am wrong, and it all reduces to determining one $v_i$.

Comment: As was mentioned, for generic $V$, the problem just boils down to considering each $v_i$ separately. The points in $V$ would need to be structured in order to be able to infer what $V$ is with less 'measurements' $\langle v,v_i \rangle$, $v\in\mathbb{R}^d$.